# Modifying cakephp request->data array

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to learn cake with a simple blog. I used cake bake to make my controllers. The Post model has a created_date field, but I want to set that on the server side (a client could tamper with it). I've added a couple lines to the add controller like so:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      $this->Post->create();
      date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
      $this->request->data['Post']['created_date'] = date("c"); //set create date server side
      if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
      }
    }
    $authors = $this->Post->Author->find('list');
    $tags = $this->Post->Tag->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('authors', 'tags'));
  }
```

The problem is the created date isn't saved at all, it's set to 0000-00-00. Everything I read says that this should be good. Even when I look at debugkit, it shows the post data has the correct created_date in the array.

Comment: What is the output of `date("c")``And why are you not using `created` as field and let CakePHP do its magic? It would automatically populate that field then.

Comment: I was not aware of this convention, thanks!

Comment: But what is the answer to the question? I understand that there is a convention for created fields, but what if I want to calculate soemthing else in the controller? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow cakephp's conventions then the framework will automatically populate this field for you. 
You have two options:

1. rename the field you want to `'created'` and set it to datetime in the
   database, and the framework will take care of the rest, provided you don't manually pass a value via the posted data
2. Use this: `$this->request->data['Post']['created_date'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');`

Comment: So this makes this situation work, but what about another instance where I want to calculate some other field and set that value in the controller? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible, your usage of date() might just be wrong. I usually use a string based date, of the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` that always works

Comment: That could be it I guess, I used the ISO 8601 date, which uses the T as the date time separator rather than space

Comment: date("Y-m-d H:i:s") doesn't seem to work either. I don' understand what I'm doing wrong, Debugkit even shows that the variable is set: http://imgur.com/R1leHwb

Comment: Also if I go directly to the database and write an insert with a date in the format '2014-11-11T13:29:00', MySQL parses it with no problem, so I don't think date('c') is the issue here

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and it doesn't result in a proper date being inserted either: $this->request->data['Post']['created_date'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');

Comment: what is being recorded, and have you set the type of field to datetime?

Comment: The type in MySQL or in the model php?

Comment: what value is cake putting into the database for `created` when you use `DboSource::expression('NOW()')`.

Comment: It says the field is an object of type expression with value NOW()

Answer (score 0):

What is your field type for the date.. is it datetime or is date.. and what is the accepted format in the database.. You can try insert one date into the table to see the format.

I have similar problem, date shows 0000-00-00, but then I realized I have to follow the format based on database. If your date is from a form, just use the following to convert it to the correct format.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->request->data['Model']['date']));
```

Change the date format accordingly.